# Radio button not working

Tags: integrated-circuit

The on/off button of my radio is not working.

[image]

Pushing the button (on top of the board) has no effect.

Short-circuiting the two solder pads (in the red oval) does turn the radio on and off.

What should I do next?

What I tried (with no luck):

- WD-40.
- Pressing the button very hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Trace the leads from the pushbutton to the solder pads to see if there is a break.
2. Check for continuity across the pushbutton terminals with a multimeter when the button is pushed.
3. Try to bridge the contacts on the button and check if the radio turns on.
4. If step 1 checks out and either step 2 or 3 show no continuity, then the pushbutton is bad and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Will try tomorrow: it is 10PM now.